# Writing data to text file type mismatch error vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting error while writing variant variable `vArr` to text file. 
In this line I'm getting error:

```
textData = CStr(vArr)
```

I have searched but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm much appreciated for your help.

Here is the full code:

```
Sub Perm()
    Dim rSets As Range, rOut As Range
    Dim vArr As Variant, lrow As Long

    Set rSets = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ReDim vArr(1 To rSets.Columns.Count)
    Set rOut = Cells(1, rSets.Columns.Count + 2)
    Perm1 rSets, vArr, rOut, 1, lrow
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Perm1(rSets As Range, _
          ByVal vArr As Variant, _
          rOut As Range, _
          ByVal lSetN As Long, _
          lrow As Long)
    Dim fileName As String, textData As String
    Dim textRow As String, fileNo As Integer

    fileName = "E:\Projeler\test.txt"
    fileNo = FreeFile

    For j = 1 To rSets.Rows.Count
        If rSets(j, lSetN) = "" Then Exit Sub
        vArr(lSetN) = rSets(j, lSetN)
        If lSetN = rSets.Columns.Count Then
            lrow = lrow + 1
            textData = CStr(vArr)
            Open fileName For Output As #fileNo
            Print #fileNo, textData
            Close #fileNo
            'rOut(lrow).Resize(1, rSets.Columns.Count).Value = vArr
        Else
            Perm1 rSets, vArr, rOut, lSetN + 1, lrow
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a break point on that line and examine the properties and contents of `vArr` when the code stops.

Comment: Why are you looping through all the rows if you are only writing the very last row to the file?  (Well, you are writing all the rows to the file, but each row is replacing what used to be in the file, so only the last row will be in the file when you finish.)

Comment: And why do a recursive call of the `Perm1` subroutine?  Is that just so you populate each column of `vArr` before you write anything out?  That could be done a lot easier by using something like `For lSetN = 1 To rSets.Columns.Count : vArr(lSetN) = rSets(j, lSetN): Next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the array to a string with Join.

```
textData = CStr(join(vArr, chr(32)))
```

I've used a space (i.e. chr(32)) for the delimiter but you can change that.

Comment: Thank you very very much.This is the solution i've looking for.